# Bootstrap dropdown stoppropagation Issue

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have an angular project running, but that's relevant since this issue is primarily related to bootstrap 4.

So I heavily depend on bootstraps dropdown in my project, and what bootstrap does is, it prevents event propagation on the dropdown buttons. And this seems to be intentional.

I have a click event listening on the document, to check whether other elements in the page should be hidden or not, but due to event not propagating I'm unable to achieve this.

Any help on the issue will be appreciated, and I will definitely mark an accepted answer.

`$(document).on('click', function(e){
  console.log('Click triggered');
});`
http://jsbin.com/galaqeguke/edit?html,js,output

JSBin for reference.

Comment: Please share code and perhaps explain what you've tried.

Comment: I cant disclose the actual code, however I have provided a JSbin.

Comment: I looked at it, but it looks like it's working. The goal is when a user clicks a dropdown option, the tagname of that option is placed in the paragraph as text, no? I don't see Bootstrap causing any issue.

Comment: Bootstrap is fine, but if you click the button, it wont say, "Clicked BUTTON", because click event does not get triggered on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap out the 'document' with '.dropdown' in the function:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function (e){
      $('#message').text('Clicked '+e.target.tagName);
});
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Cant believe I didnt think of adding a listener to button itself. Achieved what I needed by putting $(document, '.dropdown')